# Xcode mp4 video won't play on iPhone IOS 4.2.1

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a MPMoviePlayerController that I use to play a full screen mp4 video on the iPhone.
This is working great with iPhone 3gs ios 4.0 and ios 5.0 only when I try to play this in IOS 4.2 is doesn't show but there are no error's.

I'm testing on a real device iPhone 3g 4.2.1
Does anybody know whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using UIWebView.